# list index out of range in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am implementing Sentiment analysis Web application with Django as a back-end. Python version is 2.7. Django version is 1.9.5. OS is linux ( Ubuntu). I am new with Django and I found the following code from github. the problem is that, when I am typing a sentence in text box to show me the sentiment of it, I receive the following error.

```
IndexError at /
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?search_text=hello+world
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__, line 297
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/media/ehsan/New Volume/thesis/Django tutorial/SentimentAnalysis_DjangoApp-master',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ehsan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/rwthfs/rz/SW/UTIL.common/Python/2.7.9/x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Here is the code on `Models.py`

```
from django.db import models
import nlpapp.sentiment_mod as s

# Create your models here.
class Sentiment(models.Model): 

    text = " "

    # function that receives text and spits out pos or neg
    def analysis(self, text):
        if s.Result(text)[1] is 'Neutral': 
            self.text = "Neutral"

        elif s.Result(text)[1] is 'Positive': 
            self.text = "Positive"

        else: 
            self.text = "Negative"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

`Result` is a function is sentiment.py that returns the sentiment of sentence.
Here is the `views.py` . I guess the error is caused from this page.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

# Create your views here.
from nlpapp.models import Sentiment
from django.views.generic import ListView

class Senty(ListView):
    """docstring for Senty"""
    model = Sentiment
    context_object_name = "senti"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Senty, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #Get the current context.
        context = super(Senty, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        search_text = "" # Assume no search
        if self.request.method == "GET": 
            search_text = self.request.GET.get("search_text", "").strip()
            print("1", search_text, type(search_text))

        if search_text != "": 
            # get the result of the analysis 
            a = Sentiment.objects.all()[0]
            a.analysis(search_text)
            analysis_result = a.text
            print("2", analysis_result)
            # analysis_result = [a]
            # print("2", analysis_result[0].text)
        else: 
            analysis_result = []
        print("3", analysis_result)

        # adding items to context for display
        context["search_text"] = search_text
        context["analysis_result"] = analysis_result

        return  context
```

And here is the line that the error happened

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?search_text=Hello+world

Django Version: 1.9.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'nlpapp',
 'django.contrib.humanize')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/ehsan/New Volume/thesis/Django tutorial/SentimentAnalysis_DjangoApp-master/nlpapp/views.py" in dispatch
  32.       return super(Senty, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
  174.         context = self.get_context_data()

File "/media/ehsan/New Volume/thesis/Django tutorial/SentimentAnalysis_DjangoApp-master/nlpapp/views.py" in get_context_data
  45.           a = Sentiment.objects.all()[0]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  297.         return list(qs)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: On the error page that you receive, below there should be the line **in your code** where the error takes place. Can you look it up and post here?

Comment: Edited the post and added the whole error at the end of it.

Comment: You don't have any `Sentiment` entry in your database, don't you? You are trying to get the first entry (which you'd better use `Sentiment.objects.first()` for it), but there are no entries at all in your sentiment table, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

After examining your code, I assume that you are using `django` models in a slightly different manner. A django model is a django representation of a database table. And as documentations [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#fields):

> The most important part of a model – and the only **required** part of a model – is the list of database fields it defines.

But from this lines -

```
class Sentiment(models.Model): 

    text = " "

    # function that receives text and spits out pos or neg
    def analysis(self, text):
        if s.Result(text)[1] is 'Neutral': 
            self.text = "Neutral"

        elif s.Result(text)[1] is 'Positive': 
            self.text = "Positive"

        else: 
            self.text = "Negative"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I can say that you did not define any database field in your model. And your are using it only for input text analysis, right? So, in your case `Sentiment.objects.all()` neither works nor makes any sense. Because I am not sure if there is a database table either.

So, if you need models then I recommend to look at [these tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/) about `django` models, or [these documentation pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/). Or if you only need a functionality to analyse input texts then you can create a custom python class, not a django model, and use it for that.